# How does the compiler know how many arguments to generate while using @property?

Tags: objective-c

I'm studying Objective C with "Programming in Objective C" book and I got to the part where he explain on `@property` and `@synthesize`, but im trying to understand something:
Since declaring the setter and getter I had to provide an argument names, in this case it was only 1 for each but im pretty positive its possible to declare getter/setter with more than 1.
In that case, how does the compiler know how many arguments to generate while using `@property` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A property setter can only take one argument and a property getter cannot take any arguments.

It is possible to have a method that takes more than one argument and sets things, but that is not property setter.

Comment: thanks! but it make sense that i will have a setter that needs 2 arguments right? in that case i will have to code the setter and getter myself right?

Comment: As Chuck said, it's fine for a method to take two arguments and set one or more properties, but it's not really a setter in the conventional Objective-C sense of the word at that point.

Answer (score 2):

A getter does not take any value. It only returns the value of the variable. A setter sets the value of the variable, so it only has one argument and doesn't return anything. If your "getter" takes more than one argument, it's not called a "setter" anymore.